# Sticky sidebar below sticky header using a css-grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid, sidebar, sticky

My layout is based using css-grids. I managed to stick the header to the top by using:

```
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
```

However, if I try to use the same code for any of the sidebars (but with a top: 200px for instances) it doesn't work.

Here's the code to my codepen if you find it easier (https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/MWgLqgL?editors=1100). However, I'm also including it below without the lipsum.

I wouldn't want to break the grid layout by using position: fixed. Is there any other simpler way of doing it and at the same time preserve the grids?... Thanks in advance for helping this newbie!

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="header pd">Header</header>



    <div class="left-sidebar pd">
      <div class="box-1 pd">
        Box-1
      </div>
      <footer class="footer pd">
        Footer
      </footer>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content pd">
      Main content 
    </div>


    <div class="right-sidebar pd">
      <div class="box-2 pd">
        Box-2
      </div>
      <div class="box-3 pd">
        Box-3
      </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;

  grid-template-areas: "head head head"
                       "leftbar main rightbar";

  & > * {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #ggg;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
}

  .pd {
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .header {
    grid-area: head;

    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .left-sidebar {
    grid-area: leftbar;

    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 200px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    .box-1 {
      color: red;
      border: 1px solid purple;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .footer {
      color: green;
      border: 1px solid purple;
    }
  }

  .main-content {
    grid-area: main;
  }

  .right-sidebar {
    grid-area: rightbar;

     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-start;

      .box-2 {
        color: red;
        border: 1px solid purple;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }

      .box-3 {
        color: green;
        border: 1px solid purple;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I try to use the same code for any of the sidebars (but with a top: 200px for instances) it doesn't work

Apply this property not to a block with a class `.left-sidebar`, but to a block inside it. You can create an additional element for this. For example, `.left-inner` element.

### Result

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-areas: "head head head" "leftbar main rightbar";
}

.container>* {
  background-color: pink;
  color: #ggg;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.pd {
  padding: 15px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: head;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.left-sidebar {
  grid-area: leftbar;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.left-sidebar .left-inner {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 200px;
}

.left-sidebar .box-1 {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.left-sidebar .footer {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.main-content {
  grid-area: main;
}

.right-sidebar {
  grid-area: rightbar;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right-sidebar .box-2 {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.right-sidebar .box-3 {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header pd">Header</header>



  <div class="left-sidebar pd">
    <div class="left-inner">
      <div class="box-1 pd">
        Box-1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>
      <footer class="footer pd">
        Footer
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content pd">
    Main content Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
    quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
    modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
    qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi
    consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis
    suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Ut enim ad minima
    veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat
    quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae
    consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </div>


  <div class="right-sidebar pd">
    <div class="box-2 pd">
      Box-2
    </div>
    <div class="box-3 pd">
      Box-3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

And same code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/dybrJGM?editors=1100)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @hisbvdis. This solves the issue with a top: 60px; instead of 200px as I tried earlier. If you don't mind me asking, is there a way of preserving the gap between the sidebar and the header?

Comment: @Fergo, Unfortunately, I don’t know if it can be fixed somehow. Perhaps you should ask this in a separate question.